# Can a pycharm project downloaded from Github be run without installing pycharm?

Tags: selenium, github, pycharm, pytest

I have a selenium pytest project in pycharm . I want to export it to github to share it to a friend. What instructions should I give to run the project successfully .

1. Is installing pycharm needed to run the project .
2. If i generate requirements.txt file , will it be enough to install all the packages needed for running the project in my friends machine
3. please give a detailed explanation on what my friend should do

Answer (score 0):

You don't need PyCharm.

Your friend will need a version of Python and an OS that is compatible with your program.

Once you have made the git repo and your friend has cloned the repo, have them type:

```sh
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

The command line invocation could be many things. You will need to write this part.